# kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.collections.HashMap@3ee0f08 in KMM iOS

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm using Kotlin 1.5.10, and ktor 1.6.0.

When I perform a network fetch

```
    private suspend fun getHello(): Model.Result {
        return httpClient.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=multiplatform")
    }
```

With the data model

```
    object Model {
        @Serializable
        data class Result(val query: Query)
        @Serializable
        data class Query(val searchinfo: SearchInfo)
        @Serializable
        data class SearchInfo(val totalhits: Int)
    }
```

The Android version compiled fine and responded with

```
Result(query=Query(searchInfo=SearchInfo(totalhits=707)))
```

However, when I compiled it in iOS, it returns a crash

```
RESPONSE https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=multiplatform failed with exception: 
kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.collections.HashMap@2566888
```

This [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755214/kotlin-native-concurrent-invalidmutabilityexception-mutation-attempt-of-frozen) recommend downloading down to `1.3.10`, but I cannot do that as the KMM won't compile in my latest Android Studio 4.2.1. Besides, I don't use coroutine for the commonMain code (only in Android code).

This [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769611/kodein-ktor-mutation-attempt-of-frozen-kotlin-collections-hashmap-why) state issue with **Kodein**, but I don't use **Kodein**.

Note: my code is identical to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Q62iJoNOfg, except that the model and the URL is different.

Anyone can recommend how we can get this issue resolve?

Answer (score 7):

I find an issue filed here https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1450.

I tried one of the workaround i.e. `useAlternativeNames = false` for the Json serialization configuration, then it solve my issue

```
        install(JsonFeature) {
            val json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                useAlternativeNames = false
            }
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
        }
```